# AngularJS using XAMPP doesn't find the page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, apache, tomcat, xampp

I have the following folder structure:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\project
```

Inside project folder, I have an `index.html` file and other folders which contain js files and minified versions of `angular` and `angular-route`.

I installed XAMPP and I started all the modules(MySQL, FileZilla, Mercury, Tomcat), only Apache doesn't start, throwind these messages:

```
5:14:15 PM  [Apache]    Status change detected: stopped
5:14:15 PM  [Apache]    Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
5:14:15 PM  [Apache]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
5:14:15 PM  [Apache]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
5:14:15 PM  [Apache]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
5:14:15 PM  [Apache]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
5:14:15 PM  [Apache]    If you need more help, copy and post this
5:14:15 PM  [Apache]    entire log window on the forums
```

I'm trying to see the index.html file in a browser, I use this URL: http://localhost/xampp/htdocs/project/index.html but I get an empty page, in console showing this message:

> GET http://localhost/xampp/htdocs/project/index.html 404 (Not Found)

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Yes, I got this message: This localhost page can’t be found

Comment: Check if the answer below is working and accept it if it was helpful

Answer (score 0):

The URL you are trying to navigate to is not correct. It should be `localhost/project/index.html#/`. Basically, xampp sets up a server (apache and others) in your system. And your file for a project such as index.html should reside in the `xampp\htdocs\YourFolderName`.

The browser locates the server in localhost and will search through the above folder for any resources available in there. So the url will for above case will be `localhost/YourFolderName/index.html#/`

Comment: It doesn't work. This is how my xampp looks like: http://imgur.com/a/rMZ3i, in URL I write `localhost/my_folder_name/index.html` and I had put my project folder inside `htcdocs`

Comment: Try to reinstall xampp, I think there is some problems with ur Xampp